# Копирование БД SQL на сетевую папку с проверкой по дате создания

Tags: powershell

Смиренно прошу помощи по следующему вопросу, имеется 2 виртуальных SQL-сервера объединенные в кластер(SQL01,SQL02), каждую ночь они делают бэкапы БД , каждый в свою папку. Необходимо сделать скрипт на powershell , чтобы копировать эти бэкапы на сетевую папку с проверкой даты создания. То есть чтобы на сетевую папку копировался только самый свежий бэкап, из папок этих двух серверов. Папки с бэкапами находятся соответственно на SQL01\Backup01 и SQL02\Backup02. Сам со скриптами powershell фактически не сталкивался, искал информацию по форумам, нашел только информацию по Robocopy с использованием LastWriteDate, но не совсем понял как можно сделать эту проверку на обе папки.